# Can I write event handler of any control on other page

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling, sitefinity

I am using `sitefinity` `CMS` to develop my web Application. Here I stuck in a problem where I am using sitefinity's inbuild Event Calendar widget and it was looking as expected but now client want Weekends to be displayed with different background color, I tried and searched on net but I found in way and that is to write `DayRender` event of `RadScheduler` control. (`RadScheduler` is a control which sitefinity is internally using.). I could have build `User Control` for customisation but it is not only a calendar in application, we have many, with different requirement. I was thinking to write that Event Handler but since I have no access to code behind of inbuild widget so I am wondering if it is possible to write event handler of any page. Something like `<telerik:RadScheduler OnDayRender="fileName/EventName"/>`.
  If there is a way to do that please help me or suggest something different.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to just change the background colors of weekends you can use css to override the default styling. In looking at the calendar markup, I'm seeing two classes you can use to key in off of, rsSatCol and rsSunCol. Something like this should work:

```
.RadScheduler .rsSunCol, .RadScheduler .rsSatCol {
    background-color: red;
}
```